# Highlight Touch Controller Buttons on Oculus for Tutorial

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch, virtual-reality, oculus

I would like to highlight the buttons on the default touch controller model that is present in the Oculus SDK to create a tutorial - so that my players/users know exactly what to do and when to perform the actions necessary - just like in the Oculus tutorial (when you first setup your kit). I'm developing a VR experience using Unity3D and the Oculus SDK.

However, I can't find the model that serves as a basis for the touch controller in my assets - even after importing all of them - I know I could apply shaders and/or different textures but if I can't find them (or a reference to them) - does anyone here has a hint on what to do, where to go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I stumbled across it a while ago before developing my own approach here, so I'll provide an answer in case it's useful for anyone else!

> The base models that Oculus provides are part of the Oculus Integration package in Unity. If you're really interested, they can be found in ProjectName/Oculus/VR/Meshes/OculusTouchForQuest2, and the respective texures are in ProjectName/Oculus/VR/Textures/OculusTouchForQuest2. There should be two .fbx models, with respective .png files (Left and Right) and a Roughness.png file too.

I've outlined a full "how-to" for highlighting the buttons on my blog, here: https://mphillips.io/posts/Custom-Touch-Controllers-For-The-Oculus-Quest-2